# Finding what's common between two tracks

Tags: editing

I am planning on testing out my new audio interface by recording a guitar/bass piece. I have always liked the music from rockschool and the backing tracks are great so I will use them. My question is, is there any way to extract just the drums from the two backing tracks I have.

I've seen many posts about splitting an audio track into its instruments with no prevail so I'm hoping that with the slight difference in my plan, there may be a solution.

I have the guitar backing track (contains drums and bass) and the bass backing track (contains drums and guitar) and so I was wondering if there was any software that could analyse these audio files and output just the drums.

I have Audacity and Logic Pro X in my arsenal but that is it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was just about to answer the same question. I guess that, if it works at all, the drum track must be *exactly* the same track in both arrangements. Besides that, probably multiple tracks would be needed - the more, the better.

Looking for answers though. :)

Comment: I put some thought into this: Getting the acapella of a song should be possible, if you have the exact fitting instrumental track. Invert the instrumental and mix it with the full song. The waves cancel out and only the vocals should be left.

I suspect that this technique has something to do with the answer to this question.

Comment: The tracks are exactly the same in both recordings. @silvinci What you are suggesting sounds great if it will work. Could you please link me to an article on how to do that or explain in further detail?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the drums and instruments are panned separately hard right and hard left on your rockschool track my short answer to you is NO, there is no magic trick to do that.  You could use something like melodyne and remove all harmonic content and end up with something you probably wouldn't be happy with after a long time working at it but if you're simply wanting to track some guitar and bass to check out your interface then I'd suggest just grabbing a stock drum loop from Logic and add your rock and roll.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the Rockschool tracks are not fully panned so I guess I'll just have to cope.